# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error for node oracledb

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

Installed oracledb in node server. When run dbtest.js, get Segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

> export ORACLE_HOME=/apps/oracle/product/client/12.1.0.2 export
>   PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH export
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/apps/scpqa/lib/instantclient_18_5:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb');

async function run(){
        let connection;
        try{
                console.log("Connecting...");
                connection = await oracledb.getConnection(
                {
                        user          : USERNAME,
                        password      : PASSWORD,
                        connectString : CONNECTSTRING
                });
                console.log("Connected...");
        }catch(err){
                console.log("Disconnected...");
                console.log("Error: " + err.message);
        } finally {
                if(connection){
                        try{
                                await connection.close();
                        } catch (err) {
                                console.error(err);
                        }
                }
        }
}

run();
```

$ node dbtest.js 
Connecting... 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Are you using Mac or Linux? How did you do the install, just `npm install oracledb`?

Comment: I am using Linux. Yes, just `npm install oracledb`.

Comment: Unset ORACLE_HOME.  This shouldn't be set if you are using Instant Client, and you are probably mixing library versions.

Comment: @ChristopherJones, I unset ORACLE_HOME, but the issue is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Unset ORACLE_HOME. This shouldn't be set if you are using Instant Client, and you are probably mixing library versions.